# Animate UIlabel set title even if i set the same string

Tags: ios, animation, ios7, uibutton, title

I want to animate the change of a UILabel's title, even when the title's string is the same as the previous.
My code:

```
[self.firstletterbutton setTitle:goodletter forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [self.secondletterbutton setTitle:badletter1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [self.thirdletterbutton setTitle:badletter3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If I change a UIButton title it's animated with a "flash". However if I change the title to the same string it doesn't animate. How can I force the animation?

Comment: There is no animation in any case. `title` is not an animatable property.

Comment: look at this example . "Basic animating label which keeps changing its text from an array of text"http://code4app.net/ios/Animate-Label/5212fd426803fa5227000001

Comment: I hope, there is an easier solution. I just don't really want to make huge codes just for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to iOS7 `title` did not have animations, but in iOS 7 it seems they have added the flash animation when it *changes*. One possibility might be to set the title blank first, and then to the same value again to simulate a change. If this causes unwanted blinking, you could also try to append some non-printing character to the title momentarily (finding a suitable one left as exercise to reader).

Or, you could try doing an altogether different transition, e.g., with something like:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.firstletterbutton duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom animations:^{
    [self.firstletterbutton setTitle:goodletter forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: Nope. Default if you change a UIButton title with code its animate if with a "flash". However if i change the title to the same(because the random function gave the same text, its not problem) it isn't animate it. There isn't any flash at this title.

Comment: @user3341586 You're right, it has changed in iOS 7. Answer updated.

Comment: I get the following error message: No know class method for selector'transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:'. My code:[[UIView transitionWithView:self.firstletterbutton duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom animations:^{
                        [self.firstletterbutton setTitle:jobetu forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                     completion:nil;}]       I had in my mind your first solution, before i asked, but it just don't work. The change is to fast and there is no any flash/blink.

Comment: Thank You, i did a bit research about this code and i finally got it. Its now works awesome :). Here The code i used: [UIView transitionWithView:self.agomb duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
        
        [self.agomb setTitle:@"B" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        
    } completion:nil];